# Rails 3 (Ruby 1.9.2 vs 1.8.6) and (MRI vs REE vs JVM) -- comments/suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Looking to build a Rails 3 stack and trying to sort out Ruby versions.

I'm very interested in the concept of JVM, but not 100% sure if it even relates to Rails 3; meaning why not just do a deploy just for JVM if needed.

Then there's [heroku saying](http://docs.heroku.com/rails3) there's a bug in Ruby 1.9.1, but they don't say what the bug is, if it's addressed by Ruby 1.9.2 -- or what will happen as a result of running Rails 3 on Ruby 1.8.6.

**UPDATE:** Found the bug heroku is indirectly linking to: "Note that Ruby 1.8.7 p248 and p249 have marshaling bugs that crash Rails 3.0. Ruby Enterprise Edition have these fixed since release 1.8.7-2010.02 though. On the 1.9 front, Ruby 1.9.1 is not usable because it outright segfaults on Rails 3.0, so if you want to use Rails 3 with 1.9.x jump on 1.9.2 for smooth sailing."

Anyone have info/link on the subject?

Thanks!

Comment: *I* recommend 1.9.2 for the 1.9+ series, and 1.8.7 for the 1.8+ series. Both 1.9.1 and 1.8.6 had bugs, hence the release of the next revs. (Also backed up by release notes) Bug fixes aside, 1.9.2 is faster than 1.8.7, and, the only gem I ran into that wouldn't work correctly was ruby-debug, which was patched and released as ruby-debug19. I keep 1.8.7 for testing (via the awesomeness we love to call RVM) but my running code is under 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on windows, my personal recommendation is go with JRuby.  MRI (both 1.9.x and 1.8.x) has mountains of problems on windows, whether deploying to XP, Vista, or Windows 7.  I don't develop on Windows often, but I do teach Rails classes, and that's my recommendation to Windows students now.  Haven't had many issues with JRuby at all, aside from needing to use a different database driver (the jdbc gem versions).  RVM doesn't work on windows, but you can use pik (https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) to achieve many of the same goals.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I am on Windows XP Pro (in the sense that it's the OS I'm on the most, and have installed); should have said that, but my experience has been Rails is ain't Window; which it is, based on my experience 60-80 of Rails is developed on Mac... and then deploy to Linux. So, if I use JVM, does that mean I've got to use Trinidad, GlassFish, or Tomcat as the app server?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can develop a standard rails app using jruby and still deploy it to something like heroku or an EC2 machine with MRI, as long as you don't do anything that weds you to the JVM.  if your deployment is also windows, using something like Warbler to wrap it up into a war file and deploying to Tomcat or similar is really the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is that if you're starting a new Rails 3 project you should definitely think about kicking it off using Ruby 1.9.2.  Heroku supports multiple stacks with the default now being Bamboo (the one that supports 1.9.2 as well as REE).  If you're worried about gem compatibility or something else then you can hedge your bets and use RVM and/or [multiruby](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/ZenTest/) to run your test suite across multiple versions of ruby so you can deploy to either run time.

Personally I'm running a Rails 2 app on REE and a Rails 3 app on 1.9.2 and haven't had any problems.

If you're not deploying on Heroku and are setting up your own server then I would manage your Ruby versions using RVM on your production server so you can easily switch between versions if anything doesn't work.

In summary:

You can run Rails 2 and 3 apps on both REE and Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: +1 "Heh heh heh, he said 'RVM'", said in my best Beevis voice.